# Upgrading from Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE to the newest version 4.2.6.RELEASE

Tags: spring, maven

After upgrading it cannot find many imports such as

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;
import org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory;4
```

Can you advice me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which jar were located those classes? execute mvn tree:dependency to know the jar difference between both versions

Comment: if I execute the mvn tree:dependency, I get a build failure. they are located in spring-jdbc and spring-web jars.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to change version of Spring Security.